# Lookup class method returns empty object instead of user data

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, adonis.js

So, I am creating different helpers to reduce some code on my controller. So I created a class called Lookup to help me search for users in my database and I created a searchAccountKey(key, callback). So, whenever I utilize this method it seems to work however the user object returns with nothing instead of the user.

I am suspecting this is happening because of yield but when I do use yield it gives me an error.

LookupHelper.js

```
'use strict';
const User = use('App/Model/User');
class LookupHelper {
  // Grab the user information by the account key
  static searchAccountKey(key, callback) {
      const user = User.findBy('key', key)
      if (!user) {
        return callback(null)
      }
      return callback(user);
  }

}

module.exports = LookupHelper;
```

UsersController (line 44)

```
Lookup.searchAccountKey(account.account, function(user) {
    return console.log(user);
});
```

EDIT: Whenever I put yield infront of the User.findBy()

`The keyword 'yield' is reserved const user = yield User.findBy('key', key)`

Code:

```
'use strict';
const User = use('App/Model/User');
class LookupHelper {
  // Grab the user information by the account key
  static searchAccountKey(key, callback) {
      const user = yield User.findBy('key', key)
      if (!user) {
        return callback(null)
      }
      return callback(user);
  }

}

module.exports = LookupHelper;
```

Comment: If you're truly using ES6, you should be using Promises instead of callbacks for this sort of async control flow.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Promises. Could you link me to a some good documentation on this?

Comment: https://www.promisejs.org/

Comment: Awesome, thank you!!!

Comment: What did you think would `yield` help here?

Comment: So `User.findBy` is asynchronous? In that case, it should probably be `User.findBy('key', key, callback);` (as the whole body of your method).

Comment: @Bergi They used `yield` in the adonis.js docs at one point, that could be why. I couldn't make sense of their API, though.

Comment: Yeah, so I did some research and I guess it's impossible for me to get user data without yield because the yield is reserved by Javascript. I think that was mentioned somewhere lol. But it's a very confusing thing for me. It's super weird but I think I'll contact AdonisJS on Github

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword `yield` can be only used inside a generator. `searchAccountKey` is currently a normal function. You need to use `*` before the name of the function to make it a [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators).

```
static * searchAccountKey (key, callback) {
  const user = yield User.findBy('key', key)
  // ...
}
```

After this change you will need to call `Lookup.searchAccountKey` with `yield` also.

```
yield Lookup.searchAccountKey(...)
```