# Promise resolve is an empty object and not user data

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, adonis.js

I am trying to send the user data back from the database with this promise but it just ends up sending an empty object any ideas why? I was thinking it's because the yield key isn't there. But when I add the yield key it throws an error

`The keyword 'yield' is reserved var user = yield User.findBy('key', key);`

Code:

**LookupHelper.js**

```
'use strict';
const User = use('App/Model/User');
class LookupHelper {
  // Looks up a user based on the key parameter and responds with the user object.
  static *searchAccountKey(key) {
      return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        var user = yield User.findBy('key', key);
        if (!user) {
          reject({
            status:'Not Found',
            message: 'Unable to find the user with that key please try the email'
          })
        } else {
            resolve(user);
        }
      });
  }

}

module.exports = LookupHelper;
```

**UsersController.js lookup method**

```
  * lookup(req, res) {
    const account = req.params('account');
    if (Validation.isNaN(account.account)) {
      Lookup.searchAccountKey(account.account).then(function(user) {
        console.log(user);
      }).catch(function(err){
        console.log("ERROR")
      });
    } else {
      // Email lookup alternative
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is expected result of `var user = yield User.findBy('key', key);` ? Is defining `searchAccountKey` as a generator function necessary?

Comment: The user associated with their account 4-digit number typed in. I would say it is since when you don't have the method as a generator the object is just empty.

Comment: Is `User.findBy('key', key);` synchronous?

Comment: I'm not sure, would a timeout work?

Comment: Does `User.findBy('key', key);` return a `Promise`? Timeout is not the issue. You are calling `yield` as assignment at `var` within a generator function. Does not appear that generator function is necessary.

Comment: I am very new to Promises so could you tell me how I can figure out if it does. Someone suggested I use a promise instead of a callback

Comment: Yes, though what is purpose of generator function? What does `console.log(User.findBy('key', key));` log at `console`?

Comment: Okay, I removed the generator function and the yield statement. The object is just empty. Is this because the User.findBy() isn't returning a promise?

Comment: Not sure what `User.findBy('key', key);` returns, here. What does the call log at `console`?

Comment: An empty object

Comment: Not a `Promise` object?

Comment: Just "{}" in the console. I just started Promises today lol

Comment: What is the expected result a four digit number only?

Comment: You find the user with the associated key then respond with the data of that user

Comment: I think it's honestly because yield isn't there. Because when I hardcode a user object it works 100% as expected but when it comes down to getting the user from the sql database it doesn't work. So I wonder why it's saying "yield" is reserved"

Comment: [`yield`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) is a keyword in `javascript`

Comment: I need to be able to pause and get the user information from the database then respond. And I can't do that without a generator

Comment: @Ethan Why do you think a generator allows you to pause? No, what you need to learn about are *callbacks*.

Comment: Please link the documentation of that `User.findBy` method, or post its implementation if you wrote it yourself.

Comment: http://adonisjs.com/docs/3.2/lucid#_findby_key_value

Comment: I was reading some other docs and it said yield was pausing a generator until the data is there.

Comment: And callbacks don't work in the User.findBy() I tried it

Comment: @Ethan OMG. They seem to be stuck in 2015. [This](http://adonisjs.com/docs/3.2/routing#_basic_example) looks like you need to use generators everywhere and pass them to a route to be run asynchronously. They don't loose a word about what all these functions actually return - it could well be promises, but might be some internal representation.

Comment: It's weird, I mean yield works when it's in a controller but not when it's in a custom folder created by me. Maybe one of their devs can assist me. And I need to have yield in order to get the user data.

Comment: This is a seriously weird framework. Structuring a project around the `yield` keyword is more than a little bizarre.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lookup class method returns empty object instead of user data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42639380/lookup-class-method-returns-empty-object-instead-of-user-data)

Comment: _"I mean yield works when it's in a controller but not when it's in a custom folder created by me"_  `yield` only works inside generators. In your example it's not inside the generator. It's inside the callback function.